# Visual Studio 2012 - event on "stop debug"

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2012

i've been wondering if there was any way to perform an action when debugging is stopped inside Visual Studio 2012.

For example, I start debugging an application that opens a window and then uses CreateProcess() to open another program. 
The first application closes the other program when it reaches the end of main(), but if i'm debugging that application, when i stop debugging execution is stopped immediately and it doesn't reach the end of main() where the code to close the other program is.
So i was wondering if i could perform some function/action that is triggered when i stop debugging in order to do the necessary clean-up/other program termination.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Could you Detach the debugger rather than using Stop Debugging?

Comment: You are getting an early preview on a problem that can occur without a debugger as well.  If the first process crashes for any reason then you'll also have a zombie process that won't quit.  Better deal with this early.  Pass the 2nd process the process ID of the first one.  Typically easily done by passing it through the command line.  And have it, say, start a thread that opens the process and calls WaitForSingleObject() on the handle.  Harikiri when it completes.

Comment: Really, no answer to this?